# How to upload local image file on React Native app to Rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, file-upload, image-uploading, cloudinary

I'm having trouble understanding how a local file path from a smartphone could possibly get uploaded on the server side with a Rails api for instance.

The file path that we're sending to the backend doesn't mean anything to the server?

I'm getting a uri from the response like this:

> file:///Users/.../Documents/images/5249F841-388B-478D-A0CB-2E1BF5511DA5.jpg):

I have tried to send something like this to the server:

```
  let apiUrl = 'https://vnjldf.ngrok.io/api/update_photo'

  let uriParts = uri.split('.');
  let fileType = uri[uri.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('photo', {
    uri,
    name: `photo.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };
```

But I'm unsure what it is and how to decript it on the backend.

I have also tried sending the uri direclty but of course I'm getting the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -...
```

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? On the backend?

Comment: I see that you're using Cloudinary. I would reccomend uploading the image directly to them from the client, and then posting the cloudinary_id to the server.

Comment: Yes on the backend @BenToogood

Comment: Please can you provide your controller code and a stack-trace for the error.

Answer (score 8):

I have recently spent 1+ hour debugging something similar.

I found out that if you make a POST to your Rails backend from your React Native app using this json:

```
let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('photo', {
    uri,
    name: `photo.${fileName}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });
```

Rails will automatically give you a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` in your `params[:photo]`, which you can attach directly to your model like `Photo.create(photo: params[:photo])` and it simply works.

However, if you don't pass a filename, everything breaks and you'll get a huge string instead and it will raise a `ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)`.

So, based on your code, I can spot the bug right on: you are passing `name` as `photo.${fileType}`, which is wrong, and should be `photo.${fileName}` (update accordingly to get your image filename ... `console.log(photo)` in your React Native code will show you the correct one.

Comment: You saved my life. My filename was `null` and i received a super long string in my controller. By setting some filename I fixed the issue! Thanks so much

Comment: it took me couple of hours to find solution, Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

### Maintain issues with deleting and adding new files

This is how I managed to do it add multiple file upload and maintain issues with deleting and adding new files

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :photos_urls # define it as an attribute so that seriallizer grabs it to generate JSON i.e. as_json method

  has_many_attached :photos


  def photos_urls
    photos.map do |ip|
      {url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(ip), signed_id: ip.signed_id}
    end
  end
```

[See about `signed_id` here](http://blog.mallow-tech.com/2020/07/activestorage-prevent-existing-file-deletion-on-multiple-file-uploads-in-rails-6/). It describes how you can handle multiple file upload.

Controller looks like

```
  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user.update(user_params)
      render json: {
        user: user.as_json(except: [:otp, :otp_expiry])
      }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: user.errors.full_messages.join(',') }, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

...

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(
      :id, :name, :email, :username, :country, :address, :dob, :gender,
      photos: []
    )
  end
```

---

### React Native part

I am using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

```
  
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

...

  const photoHandler = index => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      multiple: true,
    }).then(selImages => {
      if (selImages && selImages.length == 1) {
        // Make sure, changes apply to that image-placeholder only which receives 'onPress' event
        // Using 'index' to determine that
        let output = images.slice();
        output[index] = {
          url: selImages[0].path, // For <Image> component's 'source' field
          uri: selImages[0].path, // for FormData to upload
          type: selImages[0].mime,
          name: selImages[0].filename,
        };
        setImages(output);
      } else {
        setImages(
          selImages.map(image => ({
            url: image.path, // For <Image> component's 'source' field
            uri: image.path, // for FormData to upload
            type: image.mime,
            name: image.filename,
          })),
        );
      }
    });
  };

...

       <View style={style.imageGroup}>
        {images.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={`img-${index}`}
            style={style.imageWrapper}
            onPress={() => photoHandler(index)}>
            <Image style={style.tileImage} source={item} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
```

Uploader looks like

```
// ../models/api/index.js

// Update User
export const updateUser = async ({ id, data }) => {
  // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
  let formData = new FormData(data);

  for (let key in data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      // If it happens to be an Image field with multiple support
      for (let image in data[key]) {
        if (data[key][image]?.signed_id) {
          // if the data has not change and it is as it was downloaded from server then
          // it means you do not need to delete it
          // For perverving it in DB you need to send `signed_id`
          formData.append(`${key}[]`, data[key][image].signed_id);
        } else if (data[key][image]?.uri && data[key][image]?.url) {
          // if the data has change and it is as it has been replaced because user selected a different image in place
          // it means you need to delete it and replace it with new one
          // For deleting it in DB you should not send `signed_id`
          formData.append(`${key}[]`, data[key][image]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }
  }
  return axios.patch(BASE_URL + "/users/" + data.id, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
};
```

and Saga worker looks like

```
import * as Api from "../models/api";

// worker Saga:
function* updateUserSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log('updateUserSaga: payload', payload);
  try {
    const response = yield call(Api.updateUser, {
      id: payload.id,
      data: payload,
    });
    if (response.status == 200) {
      yield put(userActions.updateUserSuccess(response.data));
      RootNavigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
    } else {
      yield put(userActions.updateUserFailure({ error: response.data.error }));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error: ', e);
    yield put(
      userActions.updateUserFailure({
        error: "Network Error: Could not send OTP, Please try again.",
      })
    );
  }
}
```