# Rails API, how to receive photo that sent using FormData from react native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native

I'm using rails as backend and react native as front end, I'm trying to upload one photo using formdata in react native and using active storage in rails to save it.
using one model name Room.rb and has_one_attached :photo.

Room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

here is the params received by rails, there are two (room_name and photo)

```
{
  "room_name"=>"Guest Room", 
  "photo"=>
    <ActionController::Parameters {
      "uri"=>"file:///Users/MyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/guest_room.jpg", 
      "name"=>"guest_room.jpg", 
      "type"=>"image/jpg"
    } permitted: true >
}
```

room_controller.rb to save and receive file as follow

```
def create
  @room = Room.create(room_params)
  if @room.save
    render json: RoomSerializer.new(@room).serializable_hash, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: @room.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

I get an error inside @room.save, saying 'TypeError - hash key "uri" is not a Symbol:'
my expectation after I choose an image from mobile phone (client) and press save button, it will automatically download an image, this is also the reason I send using FormData from react native.

**Update 2:**

here is part of react native that upload photo,

```
const preparePhoto = (uriPhoto) => {
  // ImagePicker saves the taken photo to disk and returns a local URI to it
  const localUri = uriPhoto;
  const name = localUri.split('/').pop();

  // Infer the type of the image
  const match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(name);
  const type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

  return [name, type];
};

const createRoom = dispatch => async ({ room_name, uriPhoto }) => {

  const [name, type] = preparePhoto(uriPhoto);
  const photo = { uri: uriPhoto, name, type };
  const room = { room_name, photo };
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('room', JSON.stringify(room));

  const config = { headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  } };

  try {
    const response = await serverApi.post('/rooms', formData, config);
    dispatch({ type: 'clear_error' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
    dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: 'Sorry we have problem' });
  }
};
```

update 3:

source code to choose an image and send it to context

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
  Clipboard,
  Image,
  Share,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';


const RoomUploadPhoto = ({ uriPhoto, onPhotoChange }) => {
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const renderUploadingIndicator = () => {
    if (uploading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />;
    }
  };

  const askPermission = async (type, failureMessage) => {
    const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(type);

    if (status === 'denied') {
      alert(failureMessage);
    }
  };

  const handleImagePicked = (pickerResult) => {
    onPhotoChange(pickerResult.uri);
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    await askPermission(
      Permissions.CAMERA,
      'We need the camera permission to take a picture...'
    );
    await askPermission(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL,
      'We need the camera-roll permission to read pictures from your phone...'
    );
    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    await askPermission(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL,
      'We need the camera-roll permission to read pictures from your phone...'
    );
    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
  };

  const renderControls = () => {
    if (!uploading) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.viewSatu}>
            <Button
              onPress={pickImage}
              title="Pick an image from camera roll"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.viewSatu}>
            <Button onPress={takePhoto} title="Take a photo" />
          </View>          
        </View>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Text>upload photo</Text>
      {renderUploadingIndicator()}
      {renderControls()}

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewSatu: {
    marginVertical: 8
  }
});

export default RoomUploadPhoto;
```

Comment: can you upload your react native code submitting form data?

Comment: @yash thanks for your answer, I added react native code that upload photo (see update 2), let me know if you have corrections for react native part, since this first time I tried to upload a photo

Comment: i can see your request is not correct. your photo should be a file object not a json.

Comment: oh Ok, can you give me your corrections, thanks

Comment: do you upload the file via file input dialog?

Comment: I uploaded using Expo Image Picker, and I don't use web, I just using mobile apps, I can choose / take a photo from mobile phone, but the problem how I send it to API server

Comment: can you please add the code for that part too?

Comment: i dont know expo image picker, but you have to get base64 content or file object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218951/discussion-between-widjajayd-and-yash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you post `File` object or `base64` content to backend. Your `photo` is just a json object at the moment contains file path and name.

Please remove the `photo` param from your `room_params`.

```rb
def room_params
  params.require(:room).permit(
    :room_name
  )
end
```

And attach your `photo` when you create the `room`:

```rb
def create
  @room = Room.new(room_params)
  @room.attach params[:photo]
  ...
```

Comment: finally I found solution, and your answer above help me a lot, here also that help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58780572/938947